# Golang invalid import path when importing from "main" folder

Tags: go, import, package, atom-editor

Been trying for the last few days to get rid of "invalid import path:"Atom First project/main/Extension" (build)" error when installing my main.go file but i haven't been able to find the reason behind the error.

OS - Windows 10

IDE - Atom

GOBIN - E:\Github Repository\Programming\Golang\bin

GOPATH - E:\Github Repository\Programming\Golang

File DIR- E:\Github Repository\Programming\Golang\src\Atom First project\main\main.go

E:\Github Repository\Programming\Golang\src\Atom First project\main\Extension/foo.go

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "Atom First project/main/Extension"
)

func main() {
    Extension.Extend()
}
```

foo.go

```
package Extension

import (
  "fmt"
)

func Extend(){
  fmt.Println("Hello from Extend func")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple: import paths cannot contain spaces. [Spec: Import declarations:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations)

> Implementation restriction: A compiler may restrict ImportPaths to non-empty strings using only characters belonging to [Unicode's](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.3.0/) L, M, N, P, and S general categories (the Graphic characters without spaces) and may also exclude the characters !"#$%&'()*,:;<=>?[]^`{|} and the Unicode replacement character U+FFFD.

Simply rename your `Atom First project` folder to e.g. `atom-first-project`, and change the import declaration.

```
import (
    "atom-first-project/main/Extension"
)
```

Also note that the package name (which is usually the folder name but not necessarily) must be a valid Go [identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#identifier). [Spec: Package clause:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Packages)

> A package clause begins each source file and defines the package to which the file belongs.
>
> ```
> PackageClause  = "package" PackageName .
> PackageName    = identifier .
> ```

Comment: And note that Go package names should be all lowercase.